# Selenium/ Java how to verify the this complex text on page

Tags: java, html, selenium

I want to verify below text(HTML code)  is present on page which as // characters , etc   using selenium /jav

`<div class="powatag" data-endpoint="https://api-sb2.powatag.com" data-key="b3JvYmlhbmNvdGVzdDErYXBpOjEyMzQ1Njc4" data-sku="519" data-lang="en_GB" data-type="bag" data-style="bg-act-left" data-colorscheme="light" data-redirect=""></div>`

Appreciate any help on this

Comment: What text u need to verify?

Comment: One one mentioned above ... the HTML code

Comment: Why? Seems as a strange test case. What you could do is verify the attributes of the element.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for:

```
String textToVerify = "some html";
boolean bFoundText = driver.getPageSource.contains(textToVerify)
Assert.assertTrue(bFoundText);
```

Note, this checks the page source of the last loaded page as detailed here in the [javadoc](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource--). I've found this to also take longer to execute, especially when dealing with large source codes. As such, this method is more prone to failure than validating the attributes and values and the answer from Breaks Software is what I utilize when possible, only with an xpath selector

Answer (score -1):

As Andreas commented, you probably want to verify individual attributes of the div element.  since you specifically mentioned the "//", I'm guessing that you are having trouble with the data-endpoint attribute.  I'm assuming that your data-sku attribute will bring you to a unique element, so Try something like this (not verified):

```
String endpoint = driver.findElement(
    new By.ByCssSelector("div[data-sku='519']")).getAttribute("data-endpoint");
assertTrue("https://api-sb2.powatag.com", endpoint);
```